# Configuration for Data Adaptors in VIsual Studio 13 using C#

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration, dataadapter

I have an application in Visual Studio 13 using C#.
I am fairly new to Visual Studio and C#.

Recently the database being called from the application was moved to another database server. Now, I am unable to build or rebuild the solution.  When I try to build/rebuild, VS13 just hangs. In the Output view, I get the following:

> --------Build started:  Project: SolutionName, Configuration:  Debug Any CPU------

I can’t cancel the build or exit out of VS13. I get the following error:

> The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed.

I have to actually reboot to get out of VS13.

It looks like I lost the configuration for the Data Adaptors.  Also, I need to regenerate the Data Sets.  This application has several programs.  There are instances where several programs call a certain table from the database.  What do I need to re-configure the Data Adaptors and regenerate the Data Sets?  Do I need to re-configure the Data Adaptors in all the programs that use that selected Data Adaptor or can I re-configure that Adaptor in a central location for all programs using it?  Same with regenerating the Data Sets.  Also, do I need to make any changes to oracleConn in programs?

This application was working until the database server was moved to a different IP address.  Nothing else has changed.

This is what I have tried so far:

- In `tnsnames` I changed the HOST to correspond to the new IP address.
- Created the Data Connections for the database in Server Explorer (can see the database).

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kind of issue would be handled by the Technical Administration people. Do you have a database team?  Have you read all the memos from them?  Have you asked your team? If so, and everyone is confused, then first try to identify who was responsible for making the change and then get them to help.  Last resort: file a bug. That may make you look like an idiot if the cause is your mistake, but just eat it: you need to keep moving, like a shark.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Unfortunately, DBA is only vaguely familiar with Visual Studio.  Will investigate if I need to bind table.